# using selenium with python to google href " Getting this error NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: "

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

using selenium with python to google `href` or click on the links to open them but Getting this error `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:` "

This is the Code I wrote to do it.

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+text_fetch # The Dutch Dress in Orange—Why?
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(7)
    Ggl_results = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/a')  # finds webresults
    time.sleep(7)
    for result in Ggl_results:
        print(result.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: where is the error? (the full stack trace). `find_element` is only going to return a single element you might want to do `find_elements()` instead when using in your for loop

Comment: please share the value of `text_fetch` so we will be able to make a basic debugging of your flow

Comment: its available in my code in in comment "The Dutch Dress in Orange—Why?" but it will be change every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `'//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/a'` this XPath should work: `//*[@id="rso"]//a[@data-ved][@ping]`. I tested that on other random inputs and it worked.
Also, instead of hardcoded sleeps `time.sleep(7)` `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits should be used.
This coded worked:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=The Dutch Dress in Orange—Why?"

driver.get(url)
results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rso']//a[@data-ved][@ping]")))
for result in results:
        print(result.get_attribute("href"))
```

This is the output:

```
https://www.dutchamsterdam.nl/321-why-the-dutch-wear-orange
https://netherlandsinsiders.com/why-is-the-national-color-of-the-netherlands-orange/
https://www.distractify.com/p/why-do-netherlands-wear-orange
https://dutchreview.com/culture/history/why-do-the-netherlands-love-orange-the-full-explainer/
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-the-Dutch-wear-orange-when-their-flag-doesnt-have-orange-in-it
https://aboutthenetherlands.com/the-reason-why-dutch-people-like-the-orange-color/
https://www.iamexpat.nl/lifestyle/lifestyle-news/most-googled-why-do-dutch-wear-orange
https://taiwanholland.com/holland-a-z/how-to-dress-up-orange-like-the-dutch/
https://amsterdamhangout.com/why-is-orange-the-national-colour-of-the-netherlands/
```

Comment: Now Getting this raise " TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "

Comment: I actually run the code above on my computer and it works fine